Semantics of insChild in backdraft.js component
Imagine I have a component called ClockFace and this code to display Big Ben:
class BigBen extends Component {
    bdElements() {
        return e.div(
            { className: 'clocktower' },
            e.div(
                { className: 'clockface', bdAttach: 'clockGoesHere' }
            )
        )
    }

    insertClockFace() {
        this.clockGoesHere.insChild(ClockFace, { ...ClockFace kwargs... })
    }
}

This doesn't work (and of course it doesn't, since this.clockGoesHere is just a DOM node). What's the right way to use insChild here?

Aha!
this.insChild(ClockFace, { ...ClockFace kwargs... }, 'clockGoesHere');

Simple!
Oh, and if there's a position arg, like 'last':
this.insChild(ClockFace, { ...ClockFace kwargs... }, 'clockGoesHere', 'last');

